# Variable is not updated when setting it inside then() of a Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The `console.log` inside the for loop does print `project` properly, with the updated `role` and `user` attribute for `proposer`. However, when I get outside of the loop, trying to print the same thing in the bottom, the attributes I changed is not updated, and all I get is an empty `project`. So how do I "save" `project` while inside the loop?

```
project: Project = {
    course: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    proposer: [{role: '', user: ''}],
    approved: false,
    responsible: [{role: '', user: ''}],
    advisor: [{role: '', user: ''}],
    examiner: [{role: '', user: ''}],
    student: [] 
};


populateSchema() {
    var proposerFound = false;

    for (var key in this.project.proposer) {
      this.employeeService.getEmployee(this.project.proposer[key].user)
                      .then((employee: Employee) => {
                        if (employee != null) {
                          proposerFound = true;
                          this.project.proposer[key].role = 'Employee';
                          this.project.proposer[key].user = employee._id;

                          console.log(this.project); // updated attributes
                        }
      });
}


console.log(this.project); // NOT updated attributes, empty
```

Comment: Use `let` over `var` in the `for` loop - `for (let key in this.project.proposer) {` - and your log doesn't print the updated stuff because you're running an async call then trying to use the results immediately after - you have to wait until the async stuff is complete.

Comment: Ok - how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing your update in the then of a promise.  Your last console line executes before the then...

This should work:

```
populateSchema() {
    var proposerFound = false;
    var promises: Promise<void>[] = [];

        for (let key in this.project.proposer) {
            promises.push(this.employeeService.getEmployee(this.project.proposer[key].user)
            .then((employee: Employee) => {
                if (employee != null) {
                    proposerFound = true;
                    this.project.proposer[key].role = 'Employee';
                    this.project.proposer[key].user = employee._id;

                    console.log(this.project); // updated attributes
                }
            }));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        console.log(this.project);
    });
}
```

Comment: Allright, so what to do to make use of this.project outside the then?

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You forgot to initialize the promises variable, but after that it went smooth.

Comment: Cannot work with `var` in the `for` loop. Use `let`.

Comment: @Paleo Great catch!